# C# post method works on localhost but not on shared host

Tags: c#, laravel, cpanel, shared-hosting

I'm testing an C# application which uses method post to get data from "**myhost/post_test**":

```
var client = new WebClient();
var data = new NameValueCollection();
data["email"] = email_input.Text;
data["password"] = pw_input.Text;

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol 
= SecurityProtocolType.Tls
| SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
| SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
| SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

var response = client.UploadValues("myhost/post_test", "POST", data);
```

for **myhost** is http://localhost:8000/ it works, but

for **myhost** is https://example.com/ it doesn't (returned 405 error code - method not allowed).

I'm using Laravel 5.7 framework for my website,  the .htaccess file is as below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “alt-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php72___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

What's causing this problem? Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1: I will place my routes that im using here:**

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'client_server_protocol'],function(){
Route::group(['prefix'=>'version19'],function(){
    Route::post('login','AppController@postLogin');
    Route::post('AuthCheck','AppController@postAuthCheck');
    Route::post('ask_hrs_to_auth_check','AppController@postAsk_hrs_to_auth_check');

});
});
```

it failed at the "login" Route::post

Comment: 405 error in Laravel indicates route does not exist.  Ensure that you have set up the route in Laravel.

Comment: All other routes are working well, it can't be just this route right?

Comment: 405 usually means the route is defined with a different method than you are using to make the request. Can you post your routes file?

Comment: i have updated my thread, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, i added these to webclient object and things solved:

```
       client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2.6) Gecko/20100625 Firefox/3.6.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
       client.Headers["Accept"] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
       client.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-us,en;q=0.5";
       client.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip,deflate";
       client.Headers["Accept-Charset"] = "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
```